# Log4j2 Socket Appender "connect java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

Tags: java, sockets, log4j2

I'm trying to use the new log4j2 with a Socket Appender but I'm a bit unlucky.
Here is my XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
        <Socket name="socket" host="localhost" port="9600">
            <SerializedLayout />
        </Socket>
      </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.mycorp" level="info" />
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
        </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Here is my Java code:**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.*;

public class SyslogLogger
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(SyslogLogger.class);

    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException
    {
        LOG.info("commit(). Query {}", "commit(). Query {}");
    }
}
```

When executing the code I'm getting:

```
2016-06-29 17:13:42,426 main ERROR Unable to write to stream TCP:127.0.0.1:9600 for appender socket: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:127.0.0.1:9600 socket not available
2016-06-29 17:13:42,426 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender socket org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:127.0.0.1:9600 socket not available
```

Should I create a TCP socket explicitly? or Log4j2 does it for me?
I saw a few posts about Logstash, is that required here?
Please note that I just want to sent the messages, without actually catching them at this time.
In addition, I'm experiencing similiar issues with Syslog Adapter as well.

Comment: Is anything listening on port 9600?

Comment: @Fildor, nope, does anything has to listen in order for it to be sent? Does the same apply for Syslog or SocketAppender using UDP?

Comment: UDP is connectionless and unreliable. So you can just go and scream into the net without caring if anyone listens. But TCP ensures that if something is sent it is also has been received, so that's different.

Comment: *"Does anything has to listen in order for it to be sent?'* - Yes.  Of course.

Comment: @Fildor, Ok, so I've configured it to use UDP, now I don't get any errors but the wireshark monitoring does not detect any messages on port 9600. So I assume that they are not sent.

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side to this client which logs the events to socket appender.
Your server side would look something like :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TcpSocketServer server = null;
    try {
        server = new TcpSocketServer(9600,new ObjectInputStreamLogEventBridge());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    server.run();
}
```

Here, a Tcp Socket is open on 9600 and keeps listening for log events as long as this server runs.
You would also need a log4j2 configuration corresponding to this server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyAppServer" packages="">
  <Appenders>
     <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
     <Logger name="com.mycorp" level="info" />
        <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now, all the log events written by any logger which is a child to com.mycorp would be appended to console where your server runs.

Hope it helps.